# c++ template class objects compatible

Tags: c++

I have a template class

```
template<int N>
class xyz{
some code ....
};
```

if I do not use N inside the class, then all objects of this class should be compatible irrespective of the template value. But its not.

For example, if I say `xyz<20> a` and then `xyz<30> b(a)`, the compiler gives an error.

Why is this so?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with that they are not compatible? What does not work?

Comment: if I say `xyz<20> a` and `xyz<30> b(a)` then compiler gives an error.

Comment: @mohit We usually try to add information by editing the question, the way I just did for you. This makes it easier for people to read in the future. Welcome to Stack overflow! :)

Answer (score 3):

Because they are different types. Even for this empty class template

```
template <int N> struct Foo {};
```

`Foo<1>` is a different type to `Foo<2>`. When such a template is instantiated with a template parameter, it creates a distinct class, irrespective of whether the template parameter is used in the code of the class. A class template is a recipe (a template) for building a class according to some (template) parameters.

Now, if you want to be able to construct one `Foo` instnatiation from another, then you can add an implicit converting constructor:

```
template <int N> 
struct Foo 
{
  template <int M> Foo(const Foo<M>& rhs) {}
};
```

Then you can implicitly convert between one and the other:

```
Foo<42> a;
Foo<1> b (a);
Foo<99> c;
c = b;
```

Comment: I think he is asking **why** they are different types even though N is not used...

Comment: But why are they different? They are exactly both exactly the same.

Comment: @mohit no, they are not exactly the same. The rules of the language say they are different, so they are.

Comment: @mohit So by your logic `struct Foo {};` and `struct Bar {};` are also the same? The language defines they're not. This allows you to e.g. overload on them: `int f(Foo) { return 1; }` and `int f(Bar) { return 2; }`.

Comment: yes they should be.what is the use of having two same classes with different names? and this overloading. when would you require to create two same classes with different name?

Comment: @mohit there are no "two same classes with different name". Different names means different types, and different types can be treated differently by code. This is a very important aspect of C++ and other strongly and statically typed languages.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you use a different value of `N`, the compiler will create a new class definition.
Using template value or not change nothing.

it's the same for function parameters :

```
int foo(void) {          // foo is of type `int (*)()`
    return 1;
}

int bar(int not_used) {  // bar is of type `int (*)(int)`
    return 1;
}
```

`bar` don't use parameter, but it hasn't the same signature as `foo`.

Like you can't assign `foo` or `bar` to a same variable (because their types differs), you can't mix instances of `xyz<0>` and `xyz<1>`.

If you want to do this, you shoud consider using a classic inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Template type equivalence rules are explicitly written out in the Standart (paragraph 14.4). One rule states:

> Two template-ids refer to the same class or function if
>
> - their corresponding non-type template arguments of integral or enumeration type have identical values

Thus, different numeric template arguments will yield different types, regardless whether they are actually used or not. In the latter case you might want to use template copy constructor:

```
template<int N>
class xyz{

  template<int M>
  xyz::xyz(const xyz<M>&);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want compiler to prove that?

Consider:

```
template<int N>
class xyz{
void foo () {external_function (N);}
};
```

Do you suggest compiler to go and check what `external_function` does?

Besides having compiler produce compatible types on the grdounds of N not being used would have been a maintanence nightmare.

Comment: okay,let me say this. keeping maintenance issues aside, is there any  loss of functionality if we say that the two classes are compaitble?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "copy-constructible and assignable from each other" when you say compatible.

You will need to define the copy-constructor and assignment operator
to handle classes instantiated with arbitrary values of int.

```
template<int N>
class Foo {
public:
  template<int NO>
  Foo(const Foo<NO>& other) {
    // do stuff
  }

  template<int NO>
  Foo& operator=(const Foo<NO>& other) {
    // do stuff
    return *this;
  }
};
```